# Need help explaining ForEach behavior in C#

Tags: c#, foreach

I am in the process of writing a small tool reading byte files from an application, altering values in the byte files and saving the new files. During this process, I have encountered a behavior in the `ForEach` loop, which I cannot explain.

I have an `array list` with a collated number of a custom object type (`ExtendedHeader`) of the byte file and am now trying to batch-edit one value of each of the `ExtendedHeaders` as follows

```
foreach (ExtendedHeader extendedHeader in extendedHeaders)
{
    ExtendedHeader currentExtendedHeader = extendedHeader;
    Console.Write(currentExtendedHeader.Time);
    currentExtendedHeader.Time = 1;
    currentExtendedHeader = extendedHeader;
    Console.Write(currentExtendedHeader.Time);
}
```

The output of the `WriteLine` is `6 1`. The 6 is fine, as it is the default value in the `extendedHeader` objects. However, I do not understand, why each instance of the `extendedHeader` sets its new value to 1, because the way I understand it, I create a copy of each `extendedHeader` instance in the loop, called `currentExtendedHeader` which at no point directly overwrites the `extendedHeader` instance in the loop (which would not even possible directly, if I am correct). Consequently, after I set the time variable to 1 and overwrite the `currentExtendedHeader` with the `extendedHeader` of the loop, I would expect an output of `6 6`.

Where I am off in my logic here?

Comment: `the way I understand it, I create a copy of each extendedHeader instance in the loop, called currentExtendedHeader`. This is not correct. No objects are being copied.

Comment: When you use objects in c# you are passing references or copies of references to the same object in memory.

Comment: [Value vs Reference Types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

The `foreach` loop or a variable assigment in general doesn't create copies of objects. Instead it passes a reference onto that variable => There is only one object, but multiple pointers to that object. A variable is basically just an address in memory and you can have multiple variables pointing toward the same address, without needing to create copies of objects.

Comment: This is accurate. And explains why OP is mistaken in his assumption. 

If OP wishes to verify this, I encourage to write unit tests to verify the validity of it. If not willing to accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are not making a clone of the object when you set currentExtenderHeader. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.memberwiseclone?view=net-5.0. This is a method that can be used to clone an object but it is not perfect. A better way would be to impement the ICloneable interface on the object: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icloneable?view=net-5.0 if ExtenderHeader is one of your objects.